# Socket.io not handling JSON in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverside-javascript, socket.io

Using the example chat application [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node/tree/master/example), I've written a simple Socket.IO application served over Node.Js which polls a JSON file using a `fileRead` from the server side and broadcasts the parsed JSON values over to the client side, where I've displaying them.

This works really well in Chrome, Safari and Opera (all those who support WebSockets).

However in Firefox, it fails **until** I start the Firebug console. That's when the handshake happens and the data is displayed.

In IE, it just doesn't work.

When I deploy the same code with SSL, it works everywhere. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? EDIT: Now it doesn't seem to work on SSL too :(

Comment: for older versions of IE you need to include json2.js

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using IE9 and Firefox 3.6.10 .. I can provide snippets if necessary!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However in Firefox, it fails until I
>   start the Firebug console. That's when
>   the handshake happens and the data is
>   displayed.

Sounds like this might be a console.log() problem. Firefox will hang if you call console.log() without actually having a console open.

Comment: Yes, in WebKit it seems the console is always there. I guess Opera may provide this behavior as well. IE behaves the same as Firefox, if it's IE8 or above the console is only available when the developer tools are open.

Comment: Wow thanks so much! It works on Firefox now, yet to test it on IE, but I guess it should work, as @sholsinger explained IE's behavior.

Comment: Thanks for info about console.log problem! In IE8 and IE9 sockets didn't worked for me without console opened so I was confused what is going on. Removing console.log's from code solved my problem.